# Combine two commands

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, rectangle

To create a list from sentences in org mode, I use following command

```
  string-insert-rectangle 
    replace-regexp ^ with -
```

How can I combine these two to form a single keyboard short-cut?

Comment: Note that `C- -` (control minus) on a region will turn lines into list items, by calling `org-toggle-item` or `org-cycle-list-bullet` accordingly.

Comment: What @Juancho said: see the [Plain Lists](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Plain-Lists) section in the Org mode manual.

Answer (score 1):

As comments have mentioned, `org-toggle-item` may suit your needs.  Though this seems like a great opportunity to learn Emacs Lisp.  The following code though does as explain:

```lisp
(defun my-toggle-item (start end)
  ;; interactive r says that the parameters START and END
  ;; should be populated from the active region.
  (interactive "r")
  ;; save which line the region starts and ends on
  (let ((start-line (save-excursion
                      (goto-char start)
                      (line-number-at-pos)))
        (end-line (save-excursion
                    (goto-char end)
                    (line-number-at-pos))))
    ;; open rectangle on region
    (open-rectangle start end)
    ;; calculate new start and end points and run replace
    (let ((region-start (save-excursion (goto-line start-line) (beginning-of-line) (point)))
          (region-end (save-excursion (goto-line end-line) (end-of-line) (point))))
      (replace-regexp-in-region "^" "- " region-start region-end))))
```

One edge case with this implementation is that it adds a dash even on blank lines.

The following is another way we could solve this:

```lisp
(defun my-toggle-item (start end)
  ;; interactive r says that the parameters START and END
  ;; should be populated from the active region.
  (interactive "r")
  ;; save which line the region starts and ends on
  (let ((start-line (save-excursion
                      (goto-char start)
                      (line-number-at-pos)))
        (end-line (save-excursion
                    (goto-char end)
                    (line-number-at-pos))))
    ;; open rectangle on region
    (open-rectangle start end)

    ;; starting from the start line, 
    (goto-line start-line)
    ;; loop until we move past where the region ended
    (while (and (<= (line-number-at-pos) end-line)
                ;; make sure we're also not at the end of buffer
                (not (eobp)))
      (when (not (looking-at "\n")) ; ignore lines without text
        (skip-chars-forward " \t")
        (insert "- "))
      (forward-line))
    ;; move point to where the region began
    (goto-line start-line)
    (skip-chars-forward " \t")))
```